# Azure app service cannot connect external resource

Tags: database, azure, networking, vnet

I have the following application deployed in an Azure app service

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            SqlConnection con;
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(args[0]);
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection opened");
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
}
```

The webapp is connected to a VNET that has a gateway to the an external network where the database is connected.

If I run this app against the database in the external DB, that it can not be reachable.

The connection string is OK.

The DB is working.

If I run this app in a VM also connected to the same VNET, it can reach the DB without problem.

tcpping works correclty.

Any idea about this? Some missing configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to the database in vnet, there are two ways as far as I know that you can follow.

One is that you can create the web app and the database in the same vnet through the ASE. For more details, see [App Service Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro).

Another one is that you can create a P2S VPN between the Web App and the Vnet which the database in. For more details, see [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet).

Hope this will help you!